# Weird tabularray behaviour

Tags: tables, tabularray, tblr

I'm attempting to create what to my limited experience is a relatively intricate table using the `tabularray` package, but I've encountered an unexpected behavior that I can't quite comprehend. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=20mm, top=20mm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    width = \textwidth,
    colspec = {*{4}lc},
    row{1} = {bg=black, fg=white},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries}, column{2-Y} = {rightsep=20pt},
    row{2} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!15},
    vline{2-Y} = {2}{gray!15},
    hline{3} = {red, 1pt},
    cell{1}{3} = {r=3}{c=1},
    vline{3-Y} = {3-Z}{gray!50}, hline{4-Y} = {gray!50}, hline{4,5} = {1}{white}, vline{2} = {3-Z}{1pt}
}     
     \SetCell[c=5]{l}Week 1 \\
     M & Ex. & Work & & Rest \\
       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
     C & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{tblr}
 
\end{document}
```

This code generates the following table:

[image]

I do not understand why cells {2}{3} and {3}{3} are completely blank. How can this issue be resolved? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

As a supplementary question, how can I rectify the excessive white space following the initial cell of the second row? My assumption is that it may be related to the thicker vertical line beneath it. Additionally, how can I address the issue of gray horizontal lines overlapping with the thick black one? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove `cell{1}{3} = {r=3}{c=1},` which makes the third cell in the first row span over three rows.

Comment: Oh, I thought I typed the other way around lol. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions:

- Remove `cell{1}{3} = {r=3}{c=1}` which makes the third cell in the first row span over three rows. You probably don't want this and deleting this row will fix the blank cells.
- I would change `colspec = {*{4}cl}` to  `colspec = {*{5}c}` to make all cells centered. I would also add `column{2-Y} = {30pt}` to let all columns (except for the first) have the same width. In any case, remove `column{2-Y} = {rightsep=20pt}` to reduce the excessive space.
- Change `hline{4-Y} = {gray!50}, hline{4,5} = {1}{white}` to `hline{4-Y} = {2-Z}{gray!50, leftpos=0}`. It is a not a good idea to first draw lines over the whole width of the table and then overwrite the first part with white. Adding `leftpos=0` will solve the problem with overlapping horizontal borders.
- Change `vline{2-Y} = {2}{gray!15}` to `vline{3-Y} = {2}{gray!15}` and add `vline{2} = {2}{gray!15, 1pt}` if you want to remove the white borders in the second row.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=20mm, top=20mm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    width = \textwidth,
    %colspec = {*{4}lc},
    colspec = {*{5}c},
    row{1} = {bg=black, fg=white},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries}, 
    %column{2-Y} = {rightsep=20pt},
    column{2-Y} = {30pt}, % just as suggestion
    row{2} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!15},
    %vline{2-Y} = {2}{gray!15},
    hline{3} = {red, 1pt},
    %cell{1}{3} = {r=3}{c=1},
    vline{3-Y} = {2}{gray!15},
    vline{3-Y} = {3-Z}{gray!50}, 
    %hline{4-Y} = {gray!50}, 
    %hline{4,5} = {1}{white}, 
    hline{4-Y} = {2-Z}{gray!50, leftpos=0}, 
    vline{2} = {2}{gray!15, 1pt},
    vline{2} = {3-Z}{1pt}
}     
     \SetCell[c=5]{l}Week 1 \\
     M & Ex. & Work & & Rest \\
       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
     C & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{tblr}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]